Can AUC range be other than between 0 and 1?
In this question and answer regarding AUC: Applying a function for calculating AUC for each subject
Why is the AUC not between 0 and 1? shouldn't it be?
Thank you so much in advance.
I have tried calculating AUC's on my own that were between 1 and 30, but assumed I was getting the wrong answer as they weren't between 0 and 1

I think there's a bit of a confusion here. Let me try to clarify it a bit.
AUC may be used as an acronym for Area Under the Curve (for any curve). However, in ML-focused texts, it may be used interchangeably with AUC(ROC) or AUROC.
In terms of the AUC of Receiver operating characteristic (ROC) curve (widely used to evaluate ML classifiers), yes you are right. Because ROC ranges from 0,0 to 1,1 auROC must be [0,1].
On the other hand, you can compute the AUC for any other curve, which is what is actually happening in the link you shared (using MESS auc func). If you pay attention to the time-concentration curve for each id in the example, you will realize its integral is >1 (which is fine)
